# Generate keystrokes in Linux from Python3

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, raspbian, keystroke, uinput

I need to generate keystrokes in Linux (Raspbian) from Python3. Something like `uinput` but for Python3. I'd prefer not to use `subprocess` for this.

Easier to install (apt-get) the better as it will be used in a guide to show others.

Any ideas?
Thomas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found PyUserInput that works.

https://github.com/SavinaRoja/PyUserInput/wiki/Installation
https://github.com/SavinaRoja/PyUserInput

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
sudo pip-3.2 install python3-xlib
sudo pip-3.2 install PyUserInput
```

And the Python:

```
from pykeyboard import PyKeyboard
keyboard = PyKeyboard()
keyboard.tap_key("a")
```