# Python PyKeyboard

Tags: python, events, module, keyboard

How can I press j and f with the module "PyKeyboard"?

I already got this:

```
from pykeyboard import PyKeyboard
k = PyKeyboard()

# To Create an Alt+Tab combo
k.press_key(k.alt_key)
k.tap_key(k.tab_key)
k.release_key(k.alt_key)

while True:
        k.press_key(k.j_key)
        k.press_key(k.f_key)
```

But this isn't working.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think this may work,

```
from pykeyboard import PyKeyboard
k = PyKeyboard()

# To Create an Alt+Tab combo
k.press_key(k.alt_key)
k.tap_key(k.tab_key)
k.release_key(k.alt_key)

while True:
    k.press_key(k."j")
    k.press_key(k."f")
```

Credit to:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32582125